# How can I set up Bubble Conversation in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I know how to make a Bubble Conversation in Android Native but in Flutter there is no tutorial about it.

I searched with keyword like: *bubble conversation in flutter*, *bubble chat notification in flutter*,....
I will got all thing about custom Item Chat with tons of library.

Some guys made it but just a CircleAvatar with Display Over Other App features not like the document in Android Developer

And it not what I expected, which one I want is from this document:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/bubbles

Thanks

Comment: I guess you might need to integrate it with android native code - https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Well, such integration is not that easy. Because Android says that this feature is strongly tied to notifications. How will the Flutter plugin handle both bubbles and notifications 